# Memory not freeing up std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> C++

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm populating a list of string shared pointers. At some point in my program, I clear the list. But the memory consumption of my program does not reduce even after I call `clear()` function of list. Any Idea why?

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "                                                            \
        PREFACE                                                                     \
                                                                                    \
        Most of the adventures recorded in this book really occurred; one or two    \
        were experiences of my own, the rest those of boys who were schoolmates     \
        of mine. Huck Finn is drawn from life; Tom Sawyer also, but not from an     \
        individual--he is a combination of the characteristics of three boys whom   \
        I knew, and therefore belongs to the composite order of architecture.       \
                                                                                    \
        The odd superstitions touched upon were all prevalent among children and    \
        slaves in the West at the period of this story--that is to say, thirty or   \
        forty years ago.                                                            \
                                                                                    \
        Although my book is intended mainly for the entertainment of boys and       \
        girls, I hope it will not be shunned by men and women on that account,      \
        for part of my plan has been to try to pleasantly remind adults of what     \
        they once were themselves, and of how they felt and thought and talked,     \
        and what queer enterprises they sometimes engaged in.                       \
    ";

    std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> data;
    for (auto i = 0u; i < 999999; ++i) {
        data.push_back(std::make_shared<std::string>(text));
    }

    std::cout << "Data loaded. Press any key to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    data.clear(); // memory does not reduce
    std::cout << "Data unloaded. Press any key to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    std::cout << "Container size:" << data.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press any key to exit...";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm debugging on WSL. I used both linux top (on WSL) and Windows Task Manager to check memory usage at each stop. But valgrind does not report any memory leaks.

P.S. Please don't ask why I'm using shared pointers. Proposing different approach would be useful but the main purpose of this question is to understand this behavior. Since even cppref doesn't explain this. Appreciate if someone can explain this behavior rather than fixing it.

I don't need a fix. I need an explanation.

Comment: freeing memory doesn't mean deallocating, means only "feel free to overwrite this piece of memory". Instead of List, use a your object that has inside the destructor `cout<<"destructor"<<endl;` and you will see that at that line, it will print that several times

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you using `std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::string>>`? This looks ideal for `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @Berto99 OMG. Are you saying shared_pointers work as a memory pool?

Comment: @AmithChinthaka It has nothing to do with the shared pointers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That doesn't help me to solve my problem. I'm handling very large objects (Giga bytes of). Cannot keep in stack. This is just an example.

Comment: @AmithChinthaka Using a `std::vector<std::string>` will actually consume _less_ memory (on the heap) than your current idea.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Does it ideal for storing gigabytes of data?

Comment: If you can allocate gigabytes of continuous memory, yes. Otherwise a `std::list<std::string>` is better. I don't see the use for `std::shared_ptr` at all here. I think you'll find the `std::vector<std::string>` working. Each `std::string` is very small and contains a pointer to where the actual string is stored and its size.

Comment: Yes. It seems std::shared_ptr works as a memory pool. I repopulated the container after I called clear. Memory did not increased at this time. It will be useful, if somebody can explain the exact behavior which happen in here rather than solving my problem. I'd like to learn why.

Comment: @AmithChinthaka No, `shared_ptr` does not work as a memory pool. Why are you using `shared_ptr` at all?

Comment: `shared_ptr`s inside your list, will free the memory. But do not forget that you are inside a virtual machine (VM) and VMs may manage the memory differently. For the windows Task Manager it is crystal clear that it will not update the deallocated memory soon, because the Linux Kernel needs to keep its cached pages. But for the result of `top` command I am not sure. Can you recheck with `fee` again. Or post a screenshot of your top command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used both linux top (on WSL) and Windows Task Manager to check memory usage at each stop. But valgrind does not report any memory leaks.

**TLDR**: Allocating memory is an expensive operation relative to other code paths.  To improve performance, almost all heap managers will continue to hold onto the memory for subsequent allocations instead of giving it directly back from where it came from.

When memory is allocated by your program code, it goes through a tier of memory heaps to grant that allocation.  When your program invokes "new" (via `make_shared`), it calls into the C/C++ runtime to allocate memory.  The C/C++ runtime, if it doesn't have a sufficiently large enough contiguous byte range in its heap to grant that allocation, it will thunk down to the process heap via OS specific library calls to ask for more memory. The process heap, if it doesn't have enough to allocate right away, it makes a system call to allocate more virtual memory... and probably a few more heaps as well. And let's not forget that memory likely has to be paged in, but I digress.

Each one of these heap accesses requires taking a lock on a data structure to manage the heap allocation being requested, and possibly a system call to the OS.  And possibly some extra effort to collapse or re-arrange blocks of memory as needed.  That's why memory heaps are tiered.  If every new and delete call were to go directly to the virtual memory manager, program and system performance would be really slow from the sheer number of system calls to do this.

Similarly releasing memory back to where it came from is also a similar performance hit.  It's possible that these heaps will release back to its parent heap when it wants to compact, but don't expect it to do that from a single invocation of "delete".

Tools like Top and Task Manager can only observe the amount of virtual memory allocated by the process from the OS. They aren't aware of free'd allocations being managed by the runtime libraries of your program. Whereas Valgrind instruments itself into your code and can hook itself closer to the C++ memory manager.  But even Valgrind will report false positives every now and then.

Comment: Is there anything I can explicitly do to deallocate the memory?

Comment: Short answer: the runtime and OS do this automatically along with virtual memory management so that unused memory by a process gets swapped out.

In an ideal world that you are likely imagining, there would be a function a function called "compact" that releases unused parts of the heap. In reality, even if it existed, it likely wouldn't work that well.

You could write your own allocator and hook it up to new and delete calls...

Comment: A hybrid solution is you create your own local heap for an isolated features or component with a non-infinite lifetime. You could write your own memory manager or just re-use one of the existing ones if possible. Varies by OS.

You could spin up new processes for long jobs that use a lot of memory. Then when the child process goes away, so do all its memory allocations.

You could try to implement a system by which objects can be transferred between memory addresses.  C++ is poorly designed for this. You'd wind up reinventing Java.

Comment: None of this likely improves your situation and are significant architecture issues. I suspect you need to be convinced that large values reported by Task Manager and top aren't necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

As Nicolai Josuttis mentioned in [this talk](https://youtu.be/XH4xIyS9B2I), `make_shared` does not call `new` twice, instead it allocates memory just one both for control block and for the resource you are pointing to, and so it won't deallocate the block of the memory until all the shared pointers and weak pointers that are referencing to that control block are deleted

however in this case no more shared/weak pointers are pointing to those control blocks, infact, if instead of using `std::string` you use a your object, you will see the destructors been called ad the `clear()` call:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
class A{
public:
    ~A(){std::cout<<"destructor"<<std::endl;}
};
int main()
{

    std::list<std::shared_ptr<A>> data;
    for (auto i = 0u; i < 10; ++i) {
        data.push_back(std::make_shared<A>());
    }

    std::cout << "Data loaded. Press any key to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    data.clear(); // memory does not reduce
    std::cout << "Data unloaded. Press any key to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    std::cout << "Container size:" << data.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press any key to exit...";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Data loaded. Press any key to continue...
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
Data unloaded. Press any key to continue...
```

So you can't see the memory decreasing immediately because the allocator that you are using is optimizing the memory, and so `freeing` memory will only means "free to overwrite this piece of memory" and not giving it back to the OS, in order to use that in future allocation, without involving every time the OS

Answer (score 0):

default use tcmalloc, you can use jemalloc with "export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1".
The tcmalloc allocator optimized the memory used, it suppose the prog will use memory next time for lots of min memory, if you use vector( continuous memory), the tcmalloc will free it after destruct it. or you can add some code after list used like:

```
std::vector<std::string> myVec;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    myVec.push_back(string(256, 'a'));
}
myVec.clear();
```

Then you'll find: the list memory is freed!